# LUKS partition is unlocked after first use

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, luks

I just tried to move `/usr` to a small ssd I recently purchased. The ssd is formatted with LUKS and btrfs. Apparently systemd fails to start the cryptography target before the partitions are first mounted:

```
Nov 28 16:12:33 laptop systemd[1]: Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Nov 28 16:12:33 laptop systemd[1]: Unit systemd-remount-fs.service entered failed state.
Nov 28 16:12:33 laptop systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service failed.
Nov 28 16:12:31 laptop systemd-remount-fs[238]: /bin/mount for /usr exited with exit status 1.
Nov 28 16:12:33 laptop systemd-remount-fs[238]: mount: UUID=... kann nicht gefunden werden
```

(The last part translates to uuid=xyz can not be found)

later:

```
Nov 28 16:12:35 laptop systemd[1]: Starting Cryptography Setup for usr-crypt...
Nov 28 16:12:36 laptop systemd-cryptsetup[313]: Set cipher aes, mode xts-plain64, key size 256 bits for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/...
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: systemd expects a separate /usr partion to be [made available by the initramfs](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/). I don't have a setup to reproduce this, but you probably need to follow the wiki on [/usr as a separate partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio#.2Fusr_as_a_separate_partition) together with enabling the [`encrypt` or `sd-encrypt` hooks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio#Common_hooks).

Comment: @Wieland sweet ... that pushed me on the right track. Care to create an answer from that? I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: done. If you've got it to work, maybe you could document the steps somewhere in the wiki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Systemd expects a separate /usr partition to be [made available by the initramfs](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/). I don't have a setup to reproduce this, but you probably need to follow the wiki on [/usr as a separate partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio#.2Fusr_as_a_separate_partition) together with enabling the [`encrypt` or `sd-encrypt` hooks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio#Common_hooks) in the `HOOKS` variable of `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`. Both of them allow you to have an encrypted `/` device, but they can probaly be configure to work for `/usr` as well.

Comment: One thing to note is that you have to use the systemd hook in order to use sd-encrypt.